# Where are pop3 files located?

Tags: email, pop3

Where are pop3 files located? I can't find them in %appdata%.

I'm looking for my outlook pop3 mails and folders.

EDIT: Thx i found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook stores all data in a .PST file if you're using POP3 or IMAP.

Find those .PST files at:

```
C:\Users\<username>\appdata\local\Microsoft\Outlook
```

AppData is a hidden folder that you'll need to type directly on to the address bar to get to, or you'll have to show hidden files.

You won't find any individual messages located there, if that's what you are looking for.